# How to include mapboxgl-spiderifier in an angular application

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl-js, markerspiderfier

I have an angular application that uses mapbox through `ngx-mapbox-gl` and i want to integrate it with `mapboxgl-spiderifier` but it is with out typings and i dont know how to include it through importing. Things i have tried is to include the libarary through :

```
import "@bewithjonam/mapboxgl-spiderifier";
```

But it gives the following `error` :

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@bewithjonam/mapboxgl-spiderifier/lib/mapboxgl-spiderifier.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'MapboxglSpiderfier' in relative path

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [mapboxgl-spiderifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bewithjonam/mapboxgl-spiderifier) plugin lib, then first have it in your app by doing

`npm i @bewithjonam/mapboxgl-spiderifier`.

Then in `.angular-cli.json` in scripts, styles array add the url source url of this library:

```
{
 ...
 "apps": [{
   ...
   "styles": ["../node_modules/@bewithjonam/mapboxgl-spiderifier/lib/mapboxgl-spiderifier.css"],
   "scripts": ["../node_modules/@bewithjonam/mapboxgl-spiderifier/lib/mapboxgl-spiderifier.js"],
   ...
 }]
}
```

After that you can import it in any components like:

```
import "@bewithjonam/mapboxgl-spiderifier";
```